# Time Complexity of Efficient way to find power of a number

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, multiplication

I have written a small piece of code to find the power of a number

Can any one tell me how to find the time complexity of this code.
and what is the time complexity of this code. 
and is it a efficient way to find powers of a number

the code is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(optPower(7, 15));    
    }

    static int optPower(int x, int y) {
        // divide in buckets

        if (y == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (y == 1) {
            return x;
        }
        if (y == 2)
            return x * x;

        int tmpY;

        boolean isYmodified = false;
        if (y % 2 == 0) {
            tmpY = y;
        } else {
            tmpY = y - 1;
            isYmodified = true;
        }

        int biggestBucket = 2;
        int n = biggestBucket;

        /*
         * tmpY/4 , here '4' can be used as a tweking parameter to size the
         * buckets
         */
        while (tmpY % n == 0 && tmpY / 4 >= n) {
            biggestBucket = n;
            n = n * 2;
        }

        int res = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < biggestBucket; i++) {
            res = res * x;
        }

        int mul = res;
        for (int j = 1; j < tmpY / biggestBucket; j++) {
            mul = mul * res;
        }

        return isYmodified ? mul * x : mul;

    }
```

As requested, I have added more notes for clearer explanation of the algorithm.

if I want to compute `5` raise to `16`

step 1:-

```
5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5
```

here `x=5`, `y=16` in the above method

if `y` is odd we multiple an extra `x` in the final result and assign `tmpY` as `y-1` to make it even

```
so noOfBuckets = 4 because of below code

while (tmpY % n == 0 ) {
        biggestBucket = n;
        n = n * 2;
    }
    that is 
 16/(2 raise to 2)

step 2:-

divide 5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5 into 4 buckets
bucket1 :- 5,5,5,5
bucket2 :- 5,5,5,5
bucket3 :- 5,5,5,5
bucket4 :- 5,5,5,5
```

step 3:-
 compute bucket 1 only and use the result of this bucket for remaining buckets
 result of bucket 1 = `625 = 5*5*5*5`

step 4 :-enter code here
 final result is `bucket1*bucket1*bucket1*bucket1` i.e `625 * 625 * 625 * 625` i.e. `5` raise to `16`

then we are avoiding iterations in bucket 2,3,4 and directly using the value from bucket 1 to get to the final result.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11032063/1002790 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/14396503/1002790

Comment: I don't understand what your code is doing. Why are you using buckets to compute a power? It would be helpful if you added comments in the code that more clearly explains what each step is doing.

Comment: I'd say the time complexity is `O(biggestBucket + y / biggestBucket)` :D

Comment: log(n) I think, but I'm not sure

Comment: Hello  Mike Ounsworth, I have added a few more clarifications to the code. please see if it helps

Comment: did my last edit help anybody understand the algorithm that i have prescribed. Can any one suggest how to calculate the power of a number in log n time

Comment: "Can any one suggest how to calculate the power of a number in log n time". Your code does that.

Comment: So In short, if we want to write a algorithm in log n time space, then we need to follow the binary tree search approach always? i mean to say that divide the problem in smaller problems and then only solve that small problem? without computing all the elements and then mearge the result to get to the solution, is this what we call solving in log n time space .?

Comment: No, it depends on what your problem is. It depends. log(n) time complexity means there are n time slices that will solve your problem. As n grows, your time complexity grows linearly. Your method of achieving log(n) time complexity does not reflect how all methods that are also log(n) are achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square-and-multiply method takes time O(log n):

```
function power(b, e)
    if (e == 0) return 1
    if (e is even) return power(b*b, e/2)
    /* e is odd */ return b * power(b, e-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that your code works with exponents other than powers of 2, then indeed your code runs in `O(log n)` time

Comment: I have a query..in my code, i am reducing the number of multiplications that is done, that is I am reducing it to the bucket size. then using the bucket result to compute the results for other buckets. can u please help me solve this in log(n) time complexity.....